# Hibernate: Criteria with many-to-many and the HashSet is null as the query condition

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, criteria

```
i have a question about the hibernate many to many query.


 @Entity
    @Table(name = "ROLES")
    public class Role implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roleSet", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
        @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
        private Set<Role> parentSet = new HashSet<Role>();
     @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Role.class, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
        @JoinTable(name = "R_PARENT_ROLE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parentId"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLEID"))
        private Set<Role> roleSet = new HashSet<Role>();
    }
```

i want to query the list of the role by the parentSet  is null 
the code as:

```
public <T> List<T> gets(Class<T> clazz){
         Session session = getSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(clazz);
        criteria.createAlias("parentSet","parentSet");
          criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("parentSet"));
           return criteria.list();        
        }
```

but the result is not i want .
how to do ?
who can tell me? 
thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

i test this code :

```
 public <T> List<T> gets(Class<T> clazz){
             Session session = getSession();
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(clazz);
            criteria.createAlias("roleSet","roleSet");
              criteria.add(Restrictions.neProperty("roleSet.id", "id"));
               return criteria.list();        
            }
```

and the result as my want.
i think the parentSet is null,so the role.id  in the table r_parent_role 
only used for the parentid and not used for the roleid.
thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you fix this issue? I'm also facing the same problem. How did you handle the null sets?